# How to fix network related errors in visual studio when i tried to connect to database

Tags: c#

when i tried to run this program in visual studio 2010 its shows an error. Like this "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server.The server was not found or was not accessible.verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider:Named pipes Provider,error:40-could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

```
public partial class tcregistration : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/dce 3/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/TC_Maker/TC_Maker/TC_REG.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        public tcregistration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string gender = string.Empty;
            if (rbmale.Checked)
                {
                    gender = "M";
                }
            else if (rbfemale.Checked)
                {
                    gender = "F";
                }
            string tcrecieved = string.Empty;
            if (rbyes.Checked)
                {
                    tcrecieved = "Y";
                }
            else if (rbno.Checked)
                {
                    tcrecieved = "N";
                }
            try
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("TCAddorUpdate",conn);
                    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode","Add");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tcnumber",txttcno.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",txtname.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob",dtpdob);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@religion",txtrelig.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caste",txtcaste.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex",gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doa",dtpdoa);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno",txtregno.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dor",dtpdor);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept",txtdept.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem", combosem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ifqulify",txtqualified.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conduct",txtconduct.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@applieddate",dtpdoapp);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ifrecieved",tcrecieved);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiveddate",dtpdor);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error Message");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server.The server was not found or was not accessible.verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider:Named pipes Provider,error:40-could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions already. Make sure the server name is correct and the server is running.

Comment: That connection string is wrong anyway. Named instances use backslashes, not forward slashes.  `.` is a named pipes name and valid only on Windows. You should use `localhost` instead, eg `Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Your connection string is bad.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and check login window.  Make sure it says Windows credential and the SOURCE matches the server name and instance (Source= server name/ instance).  The server can be a period if the server is on same machine.  Then check with SSMS if database is attached to the server.  When attached to the server you cannot use AttachDbFilename since it is already attached and the database owns the mdf file. Integrated Security=True indicates that a Window Credtial is being used which should match the SSMS login window.

Comment: Since you mentioned VS 2010, you aren't targeting Linux so the file names need to  use backslashes too

Comment: i couldn't fix this.......

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming Problem, but a networking/connection string one.

Connection Strings are their own area of experetise, way outside the normal programmers knowledge. Luckily there is a page for it: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

It turns out even when attaching, you have to supply a database name: "Why is the Database parameter needed? If the named database have already been attached, SQL Server does not reattach it. It uses the attached database as the default for the connection."

And as others mentioned, you got the wrong kind of slashes too.

Pretty off topic, but exception handling is a pet peeve of mine. And yours has some of the serioues mistakes. Like catching exception and only exposing the message. Those are 2 Cardinal sins. Thee are two article on the thematic I link often:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET